# Open a report that is made from a query through VBA and entering data for the query to create the form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 reports (both made from querys), and I need to open a different one depends on the users input, and I tried using DoCmd to set parameters and then open the form, but it doesn't work (my guess is because I'm trying to enter the info to the query but opening the form).

```
Sub macro1()

Dim year As Integer
Dim month As Integer

year = InputBox("What year would you want to get data from?")
month = InputBox("What month would you want to get data from")

DoCmd.SetParameter "[äëðñ ùðä]", year
DoCmd.SetParameter "[äëðñ çåãù]", month

If Not IsNull(DLookup("[÷åã èåøðéø]", "[àãîéðñèøöéä ùì úçøåéåú]", "DateDiff('m', [úàøéê çæøä îäèåøðéø], DateSerial(" & year & ", " & month & ", 1)) = 0")) Then
DoCmd.OpenReport "äëðñåú äåöàåú", acViewNormal
Else
DoCmd.OpenReport "äëðñåú äåöàåú ìôé çåãù", acViewNormal
End If
End Sub
```

right now it just shown an error when getting to the open report line (either one). the error says that open report doesn't support trasfering parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using parameters, use the `WHERE Condition` parameter of `OpenReport`

Example:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "My Report", acViewNormal, , "Year(MyDateField)=" & year & " AND Month(MyDateField)=" & month
```

Comment: for some reason this only works if the form was already open in the back, and if it isn't then it asks again (this time the query not my code) the user for a month and a year

Comment: You have to take the parameters off the query

Comment: because I couldn't remove the parameters off the query for several reasons, I found the way to solve my problem. the way is to use both where condition as you said, and above to use set parameters so when the query asks for them it will already have an input.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport",acviewnormal, , ,
```

In the query that the report is based on place a criteria for the fields you want to have popup boxes for. For example in the date field the criteria would be [What year would you want to get data from?]